# find a word in a sentence in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have this sentence:

```
$newalt="My name is Marie";
```

I want to include a page if marie or josh is found:

```
$words = array("marie", "josh");

$url_string = explode(" ", $newalt);

if(!in_array($url_string, $words)){
    echo "marie or josh are not in array";
}
```

the problem is, when I run this php it shows "marie or josh are not in array" and marie is the array (or should be).
What is wrong?

Comment: `in_array` is case sensitive. 'Marie' is not the same as 'marie'.

Comment: @cteski even if I put `M`arie it is not working too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using `array_intersect` and `array_map` functions:

```
$newalt = "My name is Marie";
$words = ["marie", "josh"];

$url_string = explode(" ", $newalt);

if (empty(array_intersect($words, array_map("strtolower", $url_string)))) {
    echo "marie or josh are not in array";
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Answer (score 1):

You wrongly used [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/zh/function.in-array.php), in array to check the first parameter is in the second parameter.

```
in_array(strtolower($words[0]), array_map('strtolower', $url_string)) && in_array(strtolower($words[1]), array_map('strtolower', $url_string))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 errors. First, `in_array()` is case-sensitive.  You need to make the haystack all lowercase first.  Second, `in_array()` does not accept an array as the needle.  To overcome this, you can use something like [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
$newalt="My name is Marie";
$words = array("marie", "josh");

$url_string = explode(" ", strtolower($newalt));

if(count(array_diff($words, $url_string) == count($words)){
    echo "marie or josh are not in array";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of the in_array function is a array. Your $words array is filled with strings and not arrays.

Maybe try something like this:

```
$words = array("marie", "josh");

$urlStrings = explode(" ", $newalt);

foreach ($urlStrings as $urlString) {
    if(!in_array($urlString, $words)){
        echo "marie or josh are not in array";
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use a `foreach` loop anyway, `strpos()` will scale better than `in_array()` will. e.g. `if(strpos($newalt, $word) === false)`